# Http 401 trying to use spring data neo4j rest dependency

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to "upgrade" my appplicaition from using an embedded neo4j database to use a server based setup.

I'm using spring as the framework for setting up easy repositories and it works like a charm.

Now I'm trying to include a dependency for org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j so I will be able to connect to a neo4j server. But it fails for both gradle and maven, and for different versions of spring data neo4j rest. And with a new-to-me exception of 401 Unauthorized when getting the pom:

```
* What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb:1.9.
Required by:
  :recipeCrawlers:unspecified > org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
> Could not HEAD 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/neo4j/neo4j-rest-graphdb/1.9/neo4j-rest-graphdb-1.9.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

Anybody have an idea of what I'm am doing wrong

part of my build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://m2.neo4j.org/content' }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:0.5.0.M5")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'  
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
baseName = 'crawlers'
version =  '0.1.0'
} 

repositories {
 mavenCentral()
 maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:0.5.0.M5")
 compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.3.2.RELEASE")
 compile("com.google.guava:guava-collections:r03")
 compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0")
 compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
 compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
 //    compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb:1.9'

 compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'
 compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.1.Final'

 // compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:'

 testCompile("junit:junit:4.11")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
 gradleVersion = '1.8'
}
```

Using maven with the same dependencies, I get this error:

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.emaat-sample:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to   collect dependencies for [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:0.5.0.M5 (compile), org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:jar:2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.11 (test), org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5 (test), org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb:jar:1.9: Could not transfer artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb:pom:1.9 from/to spring-snapshots (http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
```

My pom file: 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.emaat
    sample
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    sample

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0.M5</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- Package as an executable JAR -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: The spring-data-neo4j-rest dependency is here: http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j-rest/2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/ not sure why gradle wants to resolve org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb on the spring repo and not the m2.neo4j.org repo

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for taking the time to help. I have the same problem when using maven. I'm using spring boot to ease the setup, could this be a cause ? Will update the question with a maven pom file, and the exception that returns.

Comment: Please just try to add m2.neo4j.org as maven repo in the repository section.

Comment: Removing the spring snapshot repository, and only using the 2.3.2.RELEASE versions of spring-data-neo4j and spring-data-neo4j-rest artifacts, and completly removing the dependencies for spring-boot makes the project compile. Now I just have some autowiring to setup up not having the spring-boot starter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue when trying to resolve the "org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.servlet:2.1.1" dependency, as it was a transitive dependency for me.  Turns out that "org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.servlet:2.1.1" does not exist in Maven Central, so gradle is going to then try the Spring IO Repository.  The Spring IO Repository is somewhat limited, and will throw a security exception for certain dependencies.

This seems to be the case for org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb:1.9 as well.  A quick search shows that this is not present in Maven Central, so you'll have to add a new repository (I added mine before the Spring IO Repository).  With adding the repository, I was able to keep using Spring Boot.

I did recreate your issue, and solved it by changing the repositories section to:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}
```